# How to round float down to a given precision?

Tags: python, rounding

I need a way to round a float to a given number of decimal places, but I want to always round down.

For example, instead of

```
>>> round(2.667, 2)
2.67
```

I would rather have

```
>>> round_down(2.667, 2)
2.66
```

Comment: This might work `int(2.667 * 100) / 100`

Comment: What result do you want for `round_down(-2.667, 2)`? (i.e., what should "down" mean for negative numbers?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work for whatever number of digits you want to do:

```
>>> import math
>>> def round_down(num,digits):
        factor = 10.0 ** digits
        return math.floor(num * factor) / factor

>>> round_down(2.667,2)
2.66
```

Comment: just use `int` rather than `math.floor` to avoid import

Comment: `int` doesn't always round down though, it instead rounds towards 0.  with `int`, `round_down(-2.667,2)` would give `-2.66`, whereas with `math.floor` it gives `-2.67` and

Comment: I guess it depends on what OP means by round down but I would assume that rounding down in magnitude would be the expected functionality

Answer (score 8):

You've got a friend in [`quantize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) and [`ROUND_FLOOR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_FLOOR)

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal,ROUND_FLOOR
>>> float(Decimal(str(2.667)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR))
2.66
>>> float(Decimal(str(-2.667)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR))
-2.67
```

Note that you can use [`ROUND_DOWN`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_DOWN) for positive numbers. As interjay mentions [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712306/how-to-round-float-down-to-a-given-precision#comment62898732_37712409), `ROUND_DOWN` *Rounds towards zero* and hence may return incorrect values for negative numbers.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal,ROUND_DOWN
>>> Decimal(str(2.667)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('2.66')
>>> float(Decimal(str(2.667)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
2.66
```

Comment: Note that `ROUND_DOWN` rounds towards zero, which is very misleading naming. `ROUND_FLOOR` will round toward -infinity.

Comment: @interjay Ah Yes, In the case of negative numbers. I will add that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `math.floor` to "round down" to the nearest whole number. So to round to the 3rd decimal place, you can try `math.floor(1000*number) / 1000`.

In general, to "round down" a number `num` to precision `n`, you can try:

```
from math import floor

def round_down(num, n):
    multiplier = pow(10,n)
    return floor(num * multiplier) / multiplier
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also play around this using strings

```
def round_down(num, prec):
    if isinstance(num, float):
        s = str(num)
        return float(s[:s.find('.') + prec + 1])
    else:
        raise ValueError

round_down(2.6667, 2)
# 2.66
```

Patch the code with more checks like precision is not negative among others.